# JQuery Mobile iscrollview inside another iscrollview

Tags: jquery-mobile, iscrollview

I'm currently using JQM1.3 with iscrollview and was wondering how I would go about fixing this issue I have when I put an iscrollview inside another iscrollview.

My HTML goes something along the lines of:

```
<div data-iscroll="">
    <!-- some content goes here -->

    <div data-iscroll="">
        <!-- more content goes here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem I have is when scrolling down everything looks good but if I scroll up; both div will scroll up. Is there anyway that I can stop the outer div from scrolling until the inner div is at the top?

I don't even know where to begin doing something like this so I was hoping for some pointers as to where to begin/look for info?

Please and thank you.